# What is the best way to implement persistent data model in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

What I need is basically a database model with version control. So that every time a record is modified/deleted, the data isn't lost, and the change can be undone.

---

I've been trying to implement it myself with something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class AbstractPersistentModel(models.Model):
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    time_changed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)
    time_deleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then every model would inherit from `AbstractPersistentModel`.

Problem is, if I override `save()` and `delete()` to make sure they don't actually touch the existing data, I'll still be left with the original object, and not the new version.

After trying to come up with a clean, safe and easy-to-use solution for some hours, I gave up.

---

Is there some way to implement this functionality that isn't overwhelming?

It seems common enough problem that I thought it would be built into Django itself, or at least there'd be a well documented package for this, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

When I hear version control for models and Django, I immediately think of [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion).

Then, if you want to access the versions of an instance, and not the actual instance, simply use the Version model.

```
from reversion.models import Version

versions = Version.objects.get_for_object(instance)
```

Comment: Ask for clarifications in comments section not in answer. If you have an answer then only answer. Please  check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @SumanthShastry Thanks for the tips. I'm new to stackoverflow, and I wasn't sure I could comment, [as I have not earned this privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). I've edited my answer trying to be more helpful to the author.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you can work around your issue not by modifying your models but by modifying the logic that access them.

So, you could have two models for your same object: one that can be your staging area, in which you store values as the ones you mention, such as `time_created`, `time_modified`, and `modifying_user`, or others. From there, in the code for your views you go through that table and select the records you want/need according to your design and store in your definitive table.